# delegates for struct type of queue in C#

Tags: c#, struct, delegates, queue

I want to create a delegates for a class method which having stuct type queue parameter in C# but is is showing some error such as

> Error Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Queue' is
>   less accessible than delegate

Im creating following delegates..

```
      public delegate void Mydel3(Queue<queue_info> que);
```

for the method.

```
       void taskqueue(Queue<queue_info> task)
        {}
```

the `queue_info struct` is following

```
       struct queue_info
       {
       string task_id;
       string status; 

       }
```

Comment: Your delegate is public, but it refers to an internal type (`queue_info`). You either need to make the struct public, or the delegate type internal. As an aside, I'd strongly encourage you to learn about and start following the .NET naming conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your struct to be `public` like below. Currently it's `internal` by default

```
public struct queue_info
{
```